# Which method in "web3.js" corresponds to web3j's "FunctionEncoder.encode"?

Tags: web3js

I need to change a java code to javascript, but I can't find the corresponding method：FunctionEncoder.encode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're finding [this](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.0/web3-eth-abi.html?highlight=encode). You can use this function in JS by `web3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionSignature(functionName);`

Comment: I tried this API, but the result is not the same as the java one

Comment: Can you try web3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionCall(jsonInterface, parameters); If this doesn't work, can you share a code snippet of where its being used and what parameters are being passed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got the same result as java using encodeFunctionCall.